# New potted dwarf Myer lemon leaf drop? under-watered?

Tags: fruit-trees

What causes leaf drop in a young potted dwarf myer lemon tree?

Comment: Hi there, we can't really tell what your question is.  Can you add a picture and provide more details?  Then we can reopen this..

Comment: Please add a picture of the plant and ypur location